# Do we need to do crash App on cellForRowAt

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a doubt regarding inside cellForRowAt.
If I don't find a dequeueReusableCell then should I crash the app explicitly if the cell of that specific type is not dequed.

example -:

```
guard let productImageSideViewsCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ProductsSideViewsCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? ProductsSideViewsCell else {
    fatalError("productImageSideViewsCell not found at indexpath \(indexPath)")
}
```

**is it best practice to do this way or there is any other way**

Comment: The best practice is to do it with a fatal error, it gives you a better error description than just a force unwrap... Also if you have many daily active users you will appreciate that description.

Comment: @PabloSanchezGomez  `fatalError` does not  give any description, *it gives you* the *error description* you wrote yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way is to force unwrap the dequeued cell (no kidding).

```
let productImageSideViewsCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ProductsSideViewsCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! ProductsSideViewsCell
```

First of all the API `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:)` return always a valid cell.

That's one of the rare cases where force unwrapping is very useful because it discovers a **design** error.
If everything is hooked up correctly in Interface Builder – which won't change at runtime – the code **must not** crash.

Comment: Thanks, vadian for the explanation.

Comment: Hook the things in the interface builder is not the best idea... Someone can change the cells or whatever without realizing that they are set in the interface builder, I prefer to hook this kind of things by code, also I think that a fatal error gives you much better error description than just a force unwrap.

Comment: @PabloSanchezGomez Whether things are done in IB or code doesn't change the fact that this answer is the correct solution. The forced cast will crash with a clear error about why it crashed. There's no benefit to writing all of the extra code for the `guard` and `fatalError`. Either way you get a crash and a usable message.